# Проверка введенного пароля на символы А-Я, а-я, . , % *

Tags: c++, регистрация, проверка

У меня есть обычная консольная форма регистрации:

```
void register_1() {
    string login, parol;
    cout << "Введите логин:" << endl;
    cin >> login;
    cout << "Введите пароль:" << endl;
    cin >> parol;
    ofstream fout("users.txt", ios::app);
    fout << login << " " << parol << endl;
    cout << "Регистрация прошла успешно!" << endl;
    main();
}
```

Перед записью в файл мне надо проверить на корректность ввода чтоб были такие параметры: 
 русские буквы заглавные и маленькие от А до Я и спец символы: . , * %
Думал создать массив из таких символов и прогонять через for() if(), но это плохая идея( Помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: По хорошему нужно сторонние библиотеки использовать для работы с юникодом. По плохому можно `std::regex_match` для `std::wregex` вида `[а-яА-Я\.,\*%]`

Comment: @cppquestions Я баран в этом деле, только недавно курс основ ООП на С++ прошел в универе, так что, если возможно, объясните, пожалуйста, те методы, что вы написали

Comment: `std::regex_match` проверяет с помощью регулярного выражения `[а-яА-Я\.,\*%]`, представленного классом `std::wregex`, соответствует ли некоторая строка этому регулярному выражению. Всё это для C++ описано [тут](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/regex)

Comment: @cppquestions Спасибо, разобрался)

Comment: @cppquestions Еще вопрос) Оно ни в какую не хочет работать с кириллицой. Как это подправить?

Comment: Поэтому я и использовал `std::wregex`. Соответственно, и строки должны быть `std::wstring`, а не `std::string`. Если [это](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11255698/10743113) не работает, конечно